# How to make only the clicked item expand, not the entire row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I have a card on which the cocktail recipe is written. At the beginning there is just the title and when you click on the button it is supposed to expand the menu and description. The problem is that when I click on one it expands the whole row. How do I make only the clicked element expand?

this is my code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {CoctailEntity, GetCoctailRecipe} from "types";
import {Card, CardActions, CardContent, CardHeader, Collapse, IconButton, Typography} from "@mui/material";
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';

interface Props {
    coctails: CoctailEntity
}


export const CoctailCard = (props: Props) => {

    const [ingredients, setIngradients] = useState<GetCoctailRecipe[] | null>(null)

    const cocktailIngredients = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/cocktail-recipe/${props.coctails.id}`, {
            headers: {}
        })
        const data = await res.json()
        console.log(data)
        setIngradients(data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        cocktailIngredients()
    }, [])


    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
    const handleExpandClick = () => {
        setExpanded(!expanded);
    };

    if (!ingredients) {
        return (
            <div className="coctailCard">
                <p>{props.coctails.name}</p>
                <p>Brak składników tego koktajlu</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <Card
            className='coctailCard'
            sx={{
                backgroundColor: 'antiquewhite',
                borderRadius: 5,

            }}
        >
            <CardHeader
                title={props.coctails.name}
                sx={{padding: '10px 0 0 10px'}}
            />
            <CardActions
                disableSpacing
                sx={{padding: '10px 0 0 10px'}}
            >
                <IconButton
                    sx={[
                        {
                            transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
                            transition: (theme) => theme.transitions.create('all', {
                                duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
                            })
                        },
                        expanded && {
                            transform: 'rotate(180deg)'
                        },
                    ]
                    }
                    onClick={handleExpandClick}
                    aria-expanded={expanded}
                    aria-label="show more"
                >
                    <ExpandMoreIcon/>
                </IconButton>
            </CardActions>
            <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography paragraph>Skład:</Typography>
                    <Typography paragraph>
                        {ingredients.map(ingradient => <p className='ingradientRow'>{`${ingradient.name} ${ingradient.quantity}ml`}</p>)}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography paragraph>
                        {props.coctails.description}
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Collapse>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

[image: all elements collapsed]
[image: drugi element rozwinięty]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an effect of mui's `Box` grid layout – the element directly inside each grid square expands to fill the height. Wrapping each `<CoctailCard/>` in np. a `<div>..</div>` should give the desired behaviour.